# How to publish a classlib as framework-dependent deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

Let us imagine that we have two projects:

1. `AspNetRunnerProject` – an ASP.NET 6 project which is capable of loading DLLs of classlibs and serves as a driver/executor of such classlibs.
2. `ClassLibraryProject` – a .netstandard 2.1 classlib project which uses `AspNetRunnerProject`'s nuget as its driver

What I've been able to do so far is to publish `ClassLibraryProject` as a `self-contained` app. This way all the DLLs that are needed (any kind of NuGet package or .NET 6 runtime DLLs) are bundled inside a common folder and the app can be executed with `dotnet AspNetRunnerProject.dll`. This way the driver project loads the classlibs it needs and runs it all.

Is it possible to publish the `ClassLibraryProject` (which has a NuGet reference towards the `AspNetRunnerProject`) as a *framework dependent deployment* instead of *self contained app* so that it can still be run with `dotnet AspNetRunnerProject.dll`?

If I try to execute something like the last command I get the info that *"AspNetRunnerProject.deps.json"* file does not exist, because the file that exists is actually *"ClassLibraryProject.deps.json"*?
Simple copying of this file to desired name does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After researching for a few days I came to the following conclusions:

1. Find the `ClassLibraryProject.runtimeconfig.json` file in the published artifacts and rename it to `AspNetRunnerProject.runtimeconfig.json`
2. Execute the app with `dotnet AspNetRunnerProject.dll`

Alternatively it is possible to have a global `appname.runtimeconfig.json` file which could be used across multiple such projects.

For more info check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/#runtimeconfigjson